# What is an acceptable way to print from app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to print from App Maker. I have a guess management app and I need a way to print out guest passes from app maker. I have some ideas, but I'm not sure what would work or be the acceptable best practice. These will print out on a 4x6 thermal printer. Any working examples would be greatly appreciated. I've only managed to get option two below to work without css formatting.

1) Open the guest info in a page fragment and print it. This would need to print the page fragment as displayed, unsure if this is possible in app maker.

2) Create an html page by passing the guests information, open the page in a new tab and use windows print.

3) Use a mailmerge of sort on a document on google drive and print with cloud print. I'm worried that the lag time might make this slow. I'm also unsure if it's doable.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to manually print them.

You could have a 'Visitor Card' template saved as either a Google Document or Google Sheet. When the visitor signs in, duplicate that document, write your visitors information to the appropriate cells/positions, then save as a PDF in a Google Drive location.

All of the above can automated, so you'll simply have to have a tab open at the Drive location and then print the file once saved. The saving process shouldn't take any longer than 5-10 seconds, which I think is a reasonable timeframe.

Another option, which is more technical, is you directly send a request to your printer to print. Although, this would depend on your printer and technical capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, I've been testing this solutions. The template and filling it in is trivial but I'm stuck on trying to send it to the printer or cloud print. Having the user open and print it from the drive would be an added step that I would like to bypass.